# QT 5 - load images from the same folder as the stylesheet (.qss)

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

In my QT app I allowed users to load .qss stylesheets as a custom theme.
This however is problematic since they could not load images in the styles initially.
After a bit of digging it happens that relative paths in the stylesheet are resolved towards the current working dir, and not towards the stylesheet path (which QT cannot know since we load it as a string).

So the only "hack" that I could come up with is to change the current working path to the folder where the stylesheet is located, like so:

```
if (KreatorSettings::instance().customTheme().isNull() == false) {
  QString qsFileName(KreatorSettings::instance().customTheme());
  QFile qfFile(qsFileName);
  if (qfFile.exists()) {
      if (qfFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)) {
          QDir::setCurrent(QFileInfo(qsFileName).absolutePath()); // needed
          qApp->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String(qfFile.readAll()));
          loadedCustom = true;
      }
  }
```

This is an example of how the images are defined in the stylesheet:

```
QCheckBox::indicator:checked
{
  image:url(icon_checkbox_checked.png);
}
```

This is obviously not the right way, since I need to keep that current working path for the "skin" to work.
Is there a way in qss to use path relative to the stylesheet or some other method to use paths that do not require either embedding resources or changing the current working dir? Maybe we can tell QT what is the stylesheet root folder so it resolves from there? I have no clue, so need your help.

I would hope there is something like in CSS, or else the QT team made some major mistake in the design making the *.qss files unfit for user customization.

Comment: What about parsing the style file and converting all the `image:url(...)` things to an absolute path ?

Comment: as a last resort that could also work, however if the Styling in QT has some ```setStylesheetHome(path)``` and stlyesheets can use some ```image:url(~/a.png)``` syntax or something that achieves a similar function would be much better because it does not break an intended framework interaction (relative path resolving)

Comment: and now having said that, I could instruct them to use ~/ as a prefix for the images and replace that with the path of the stylesheet. that would allow for it without breaking anything if I don't find a proper framework method to do it

Comment: Add you qss and images to a resource file so the paths do not change during runtime.

Comment: @chehrlic that's not possible since the qss is loaded and unloaded in runtime by users, if it was a static thing it would be easy